# Call a property all the times or assign the value to a variable and use it

Tags: c#, performance, properties, clr

Consider the following class -

```
Class A 
{
   CustomObject propertyA {get;set;}
}
```

In a method in the program , propertyA is used via classA object like this -

```
void Main()
 {
   A a= new A();
   // use of propertyA
   a.PropertyA *****
   a.PropertyA *****
   a.Property.******
 }
```

would it improve performance of the program if value of a.properyA is assigned to a variable first and then that variable is used at all the places or it only improves code readability. given below is code -

```
void Main()
 {
   A a= new A();
   var propertyA = a.PropertyA; 
   // use of propertyA
   propertyA *****
   propertyA *****
   propertyA.******
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very small chance that there might be an incredibly minor improvement in performance in the generated IL, depending on your context and your use, although in my test case two additional instructions were added to deal with the additional (unnecessary in my opinion) property.

That said, this is most likely a premature optimization and certainly not a guaranteed performance improvement.  There is no guarantee that either the CLR nor the JITter will not optimize away the assignment.

Your best rule of thumb is to write maintainable, readable code and only worry about these types of optimizations if you notice a performance issue.  In most cases the compiler or the jitter will be able to optimize better than you would to begin with.

Comment: ok. if the property is doing calculations internally then it makes sense to use a variable and assign the property value to it. I guess.